# Question on integral equality using the average value of a function

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be an open,bounded and connected set with boundary $\Gamma =\partial \Omega$. Consider also $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Gamma))\cap H^1(0,T;H^1(\Gamma)^{\ast})$.

> It holds that: $\int_{\Gamma} u^2=\int_{\Gamma} u(u-\bar u) +{\vert
>  \vert u \vert \vert}^2_{L^1(\Gamma)}$ where $\bar
>  u=\frac{1}{|\Gamma|}\int_{\Gamma} u$ (the average value of $u$ over
>   $\Gamma$)

I cannot understand this equality. I only see:

$\int_{\Gamma} u(u-\bar u) +{\vert \vert u \vert \vert}^2_{L^1(\Gamma)}=\int_{\Gamma} u^2-\frac{1}{|\Gamma|}\int_{\Gamma} u \int_{\Gamma} u+(\int_{\Gamma} u)^2$

So is there any missing term or am I wrong? I think it's quite simple but my head stuck there so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are asking whether $\int_{\Gamma} (u\overline{u}) = (\int_{\Gamma} |u|)^2$. This seems right only in special cases ($u\ge 0$ and $|\Gamma|=1$).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Exactly. So indeed something is missing here.. Thanks a lot!